# Cat several files into one file with the file name before the data

Tags: linux, awk, find, cat

I have several log files with data in them. What i want to do is cat all these files into one file. But before the data goes in i want the file name to be there without the extension. For Example:
Files I have:

```
file1.log file2.log file3.log
```

The file that i want: all.log

all.log to have in it:

```
file1
    file1's data
file2
    file2's data
file3
    file3's data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using awk

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", FILENAME); print FILENAME} 1' file*.log >all.log
```

`FNR` is the file record number.  It is one at the beginning of each file.  Thus, the test `FNR==1` tells us if we are at the beginning of a file.  If we are, then we remove the extension from the filename using `sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", FILENAME)` and then we print it.

The final `1` in the program is awk's cryptic way of saying print-this-line.

The redirection `>all.log` saves all the output in file `all.log`.

#### Using shell

```
for f in file*.log; do echo "${f%.*}"; cat "$f"; done >all.log
```

Or:

```
for f in file*.log
do 
    echo "${f%.*}"
    cat "$f"
done >all.log
```

In shell, `for f in file*.log; do` starts a loop over all files matching the glob `file*.log`.  The statement `echo "${f%.*}"` prints the file name minus the extension.  `${f%.*}` is an example of *suffix removal*.  `cat "$f"` prints the contents of the file.  `done >all.log` terminates the loop and saves all the output in `all.log`.

This loop will work correctly even if file names contain spaces, tabs, newlines, or other difficult characters.

Comment: Thanks a million! Using awk worked! I just did your awk command like:           awk 'FNR==1{sub(/[.][^.]*$/, "", FILENAME); print FILENAME} 1' file*.log > all.log              and that worked!

Comment: @SpencerMichealBell Glad it worked.  awk is a very flexible tool.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two files:

foo:

```
a
b
c
```

bar:

```
d
e
f
```

Using Perl:

`perl -lpe 'print $ARGV if $. == 1; close(ARGV) if eof' foo bar > all.log`

```
foo
a
b
c
bar
d
e
f
```

`$.` is the line number
`$ARGV` is the name of the current file
`close(ARGV) if eof` resets the line number at the end of each file

Using grep:

`grep '' foo bar > all.log`

```
foo:a
foo:b
foo:c
bar:d
bar:e
bar:f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls file*`; do `echo $i | awk -F"." '{print $1}' >> all.log; cat $i >> all.log`; done
```